# Bootgrid custom length dropdown is it possible?

Tags: jquery-plugins, jquery-bootgrid

I'm trying to create custom table length dropdown which is not in the table header, I overwrite the header with

```
    templates: {
        header: ""
    },
```

so I would like to replicate it in some other place. How can I do that is it possible? Thanks in advance.